# How to remove some endpoints?

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm following the example of Coffeeshop in loopback documentation.
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Introducing+the+Coffee+Shop+Reviews+app

I want to remove some endpoints, for example:

- [DELETE] /Reviewers/{id}/accessTokens
- [DELETE] /Reviewers/{id}

I modified the file "commom/models/reviewer.js" and added the following code:

```
module.exports = function(Reviewer) {
    Reviewer.disableRemoteMethod('__destroyById__accessTokens', false);
    Reviewer.disableRemoteMethod('deleteById', false);
};
```

The problem is that these endpoints continue to appear in explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

Exposing and hiding models, methods, and endpoints

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-HidingmethodsandRESTendpoints